# Using awk to replace and add text

Tags: awk, grep

I have the following .txt file:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
##Tassel=<ID=GenotypeTable,Version=5,Description="Reference allele is not known. The major allele was used as reference allele">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=AD,Number=.,Type=Integer,Description="Allelic depths for the reference and alternate alleles in the order listed">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth (only filtered reads used for calling)">
##FORMAT=<ID=GQ,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Genotype Quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=PL,Number=G,Type=Float,Description="Normalized, Phred-scaled likelihoods for AA,AB,BB genotypes where A=ref and B=alt; not applicable if site is not biallelic">
##INFO=<ID=NS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of Samples With Data">
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total Depth">
##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Allele Frequency">
##bcftools_viewVersion=1.12-57-g0c2765b+htslib-1.12-45-g1830551
##bcftools_viewCommand=view -h 20Perc.SNPs.mergedAll.vcf; Date=Tue Sep 28 09:46:59 2021
```

I would like to make two edits to this text.  First, in the line:

```
##FORMAT=<ID=PL,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Normalized, Phred-scaled likelihoods for AA,AB,BB genotypes where A=ref and B=alt; not applicable if site is not biallelic">
```

I would like to replace "Number=." with "Number=G"

And immediately after the after the line:

```
##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Allele Frequency">
```

I would like to add a new line of text (& and line break):

```
##INFO=<ID=QualityScore,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Quality score">
```

I was wondering if this could be done with one or two awk commands.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is similar to @Daweo. Consider this script, replace.awk:

```
/^##FORMAT/ { sub(/Number=\./, "Number=G") }

/##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Allele Frequency">/ {
    print
    print "##INFO=<ID=QualityScore,Number=.,Type=Float,Description=\"Quality score\">"
    next
}

1
```

Run it:

```
awk -f replace.awk file.txt
```

Notes

- The first line is easy to understand. It is a straight replace
- The next group of lines deals with your second requirements. First, the `print` statement prints out the current line
- The next `print` statement prints out your data
- The `next` command skips to the next line
- Finally, the pattern `1` tells awk to print every lines

Answer (score 1):

I would GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
##Tassel=<ID=GenotypeTable,Version=5,Description="Reference allele is not known. The major allele was used as reference allele">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=AD,Number=.,Type=Integer,Description="Allelic depths for the reference and alternate alleles in the order listed">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth (only filtered reads used for calling)">
##FORMAT=<ID=GQ,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Genotype Quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=PL,Number=G,Type=Float,Description="Normalized, Phred-scaled likelihoods for AA,AB,BB genotypes where A=ref and B=alt; not applicable if site is not biallelic">
##INFO=<ID=NS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of Samples With Data">
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total Depth">
##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Allele Frequency">
##bcftools_viewVersion=1.12-57-g0c2765b+htslib-1.12-45-g1830551
##bcftools_viewCommand=view -h 20Perc.SNPs.mergedAll.vcf; Date=Tue Sep 28 09:46:59 2021
```

then

```
awk '/##FORMAT=<ID=PL/{gsub("Number=\\.","Number=G")}/##INFO=<ID=AF/{print;print "##INFO=<ID=QualityScore,Number=.,Type=Float,Description=\x22Quality score\x22>";next}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
##Tassel=<ID=GenotypeTable,Version=5,Description="Reference allele is not known. The major allele was used as reference allele">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=AD,Number=.,Type=Integer,Description="Allelic depths for the reference and alternate alleles in the order listed">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth (only filtered reads used for calling)">
##FORMAT=<ID=GQ,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Genotype Quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=PL,Number=G,Type=Float,Description="Normalized, Phred-scaled likelihoods for AA,AB,BB genotypes where A=ref and B=alt; not applicable if site is not biallelic">
##INFO=<ID=NS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of Samples With Data">
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total Depth">
##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Allele Frequency">
##INFO=<ID=QualityScore,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Quality score">
##bcftools_viewVersion=1.12-57-g0c2765b+htslib-1.12-45-g1830551
##bcftools_viewCommand=view -h 20Perc.SNPs.mergedAll.vcf; Date=Tue Sep 28 09:46:59 2021
```

Explanation: If current line contains `##FORMAT=<ID=PL` change `Number=\\.` to `Number=G` (note \ are required to get literal . rather than . meaning any character). If current line contains `##INFO=<ID=AF` print it and then print `##INFO=<ID=QualityScore,Number=.,Type=Float,Description=\x22Quality score\x22>` (`\x22` is hex escape code for `"`, `"` could not be used inside `"` delimited string) and go to next line. Final `print`-ing is for all lines but those containing `##INFO=<ID=AF` as these have own `print`-ing.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*